# regular expression with php for replace some tags

Tags: php, regex

I wanted to replace some tags like `[b],[/b],[i],[/i],[h1],[/h1]` so on. I have done this so far:

```
preg_replace("'\[.*\]'i", "",$strmessage);
```

still now it works. But it insert a `&lt;br&gt;` eveytime when it replace. I need just replace this tag by a space. I don't a `<br>` tag what it always inserted now. I think its need small modification. Thanks in advance ....

Comment: There's no way that code adds a `<br>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('{\[.*?\]}i', "",$strmessage);
```

it remove anythig in [ ]

Comment: Hey JOE its working :D :D  could you please explain me this and please give some good resources link to learn regular expression. many many thanks .....

Comment: {\[.*?\]} match first [ and nearest ] , {\[.*\]} match first [ and last ] in same line

Answer (score 0):

use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) it will make your life wasy